# How do you form this term that you get $\frac{3k^{2}+3k}{k^{4}+k^{3}}=\frac{3k}{k^{3}}$?

Tags: calculus, analysis

How do you form this term that you get $$\frac{3k^{2}+3k}{k^{4}+k^{3}}=\frac{3k}{k^{3}}$$?

I know that both are the same but I don't know how we can get to this... Tried to exclude $k$ but it didn't give me that solution. I'm absolutely sure that $3$ has been excluded to get this but what did you do with the $k's$?

$$3\cdot\frac{k(k+1)}{k(k^{3}+k^{2})}=\frac{3(k+1)}{k^{3}+k^{2}}$$

I could try till tomorrow and no solution, anyone can tell me please?

This is no homework, as all my other questions. I'm asking to understand only.

Comment: Notice that $k\neq -1$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simplify the numerator and denominator:
$$\dfrac{3k^{2}+3k}{k^{4}+k^{3}}=\dfrac{3k(k+1)}{k^{3}(k+1)}$$

This is equal to

$$\frac{3k^{2}+3k}{k^{4}+k^{3}}=\frac{3k}{k^{3}}$$

Comment: Oh alright thanks a lot :)